# Angular Bad Request

Tags: angular, put, bad-request, angular-reactive-forms

I am having a problem when I try to edit data. Server is responsing with "Bad request". Bellow is my code.

Service.ts:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ArticlesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getArticleById(id: number) {
    return this.http.get('http://18.192.182.140/api/articles/' + id);
  }

  updateArticle(id: number, data: Article) {
    return this.http.put('http://18.192.182.140/api/articles/' + id + '? 
      api_token=9aK4W3D7NpbWwPzJmUOIcyPmyehl0PHZLWP14rzQqKzUPtcFCo0Tn051CvwN',
      data);
    }
  }
```

Component.ts:

```
export class EditArticleComponent implements OnInit {

  editArticle = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl(''),
    body: new FormControl(''),
    categoryId: new FormControl()
  });

  constructor(private articleService: ArticlesService, private router: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.articleService.getArticleById(this.router.snapshot.params.id)
      .subscribe((response: Article) => {
         this.editArticle = new FormGroup({
           title: new FormControl(response.data.title),
           body: new FormControl(response.data.body),
           categoryId: new FormControl(response.data.category_id)
         });
      });
  }

  updateArticle() {
    this.articleService.updateArticle(this.router.snapshot.params.id, 
      this.editArticle.value).subscribe((response: Article) => {
         console.log(response.data);
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
     });
    }
  }
```

Componet.html:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
   <form [formGroup]="editArticle" (ngSubmit)="updateArticle()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-label">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Title" 
        formControlName="title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Body</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Body" 
        formControlName="body">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Category ID</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Category ID" 
        formControlName="categoryId">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" routerLink="/admin">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

This is error that i get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOGy9.png)

This is data from the server (how should it look):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkoGu.png)

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: The problem is with the server not the angular app

Comment: Oh but isn't error 400 client side error?

Comment: Make sure your request to the server passes in the exact correct parameters needed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server is expecting

```
title
body
category_id
```

but you're passing

```
title
body
categoryId  <--- should be category_id
```